# Tree-shaking and Angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

As you may know, you can add global libraries to the `scripts`-property in the `angular-cli.son`.

I was wondering if these scripts are also taken into account for the tree-shaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. These are not taken into account when by WebPack tree shaking.

Only the files that are imoorted and bundled are tree shaken.

Note, WebPack tree shaking with Typescript has a lot of issues at the moment. You won't yet see the same benefits as Rollup, yet.